# Drupal 8: updating node programmatically does not update the state of the node in a view

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-views

I've got an "agency" node type which has a boolean field called "has_subscription".

Then I've got a view that only shows the agencies that have "has_subscription" true.

All good.

I'm updating the value of the field programmatically like this:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$node->set("field_has_subscription", 1);
$node->save();
```

If I then edit the node, I can see that the checkbox for the boolean field is now checked. Great.

However, the view is still not displaying this node. It only starts appearing  if I save the node edit page.

Is there anything I need to add to the code?

Comment: I've just noticed that this happens on the production site only. On my local environment it works fine. So maybe it has to do with caching? (How come then it works if I save the node through the edit page, but not when I do so programmatically?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set node to published on save

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$node = Node::load($nid); 
//set value for field
$node->field_has_subscription->value = TRUE;
// set node to publish 
$node->setPublished(TRUE);
//save to update node
$node->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll mark this one as the accepted answer as it worked for me, but it could well be that the other two answers also work - the key might have been to use $node = Node::load($nid);  rather than node_load($nid).

Comment: yes node_load is going to depreciated and will be removed before Drupal 9.0. Use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load() is the best method to load node.

Comment: It seems that `setPublished()` method does not require any arguments and has a counterpart called `setUnpublished()`, at least that is true for Drupal 9 and 10.
Both of those methods are also chainable, which allows calling that as `$node->setPublished()->save();`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Drupal 8 then please rewrite below code in your file and check it.

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$node = Node::load($nid);

//set value for field
$node->field_has_subscription->value = TRUE;

//save to update node
$node->save();
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference. It works fine and updates the field on the node, but the view still doesn't show the node. It only does it if I go to the node edit form and submits it.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
$node  =  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
$node->set('field_has_subscription', 1);
$node->save();
```